# How to properly use Google Tag script in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I read [How to load Google Tag Manager with next/script component (Next.js 11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68115650/how-to-load-google-tag-manager-with-next-script-component-next-js-11) and I also read [this doc page](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-script-for-ga).

But none of them solved my problem.

I want to include Google Tag on many of my sites that are developed using nextjs. Thus I have creatd a simple reusable component:

```
import Script from 'next/script'

const GoogleTag = ({ identifier }) => {
    if (!identifier || !identifier.startsWith('G-')) {
        throw new Error('Google tag id is not correct;');
    }
    return <>
        <Script
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${identifier}`}
            strategy="afterInteractive"
        />
        <Script id="google-analytics" strategy="afterInteractive">
            {`
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());

          gtag('config', '${identifier}');
        `}
        </Script>
    </>
}

export default GoogleTag;
```

And I use it in each of my sites, in the `_app.js` file, this way:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import GoogleTag from '../Base/GoogleTag';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <GoogleTag identifier='G-9XLT855ZE0' />
            </Head>
            <div>
                application code comes here
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

But I don't see Google Tag script being loaded in the Chrom's Dev Tools, int Networks tab.

Comment: [`next/script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) should not be used inside `next/head`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly use the `google tag` in your `next.js` app, You should add the GTM script to `_document.js` in the `Head` section.

example code `_documents.js`, [source.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-google-analytics)

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

import { GA_TRACKING_ID } from '../lib/gtag'

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
          <script
            async
            src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
          />
          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
              page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}
```

To set up google analytics page view for single page app, and other methods of using GT in next.js. You can visit this [source1](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/), [source2](https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/9/easiest-way-to-integrate-google-analytics-with-react-js-and-next-js).

Comment: What's the difference between `_app.js` and `_document.js` from the point of `<Head>` component? Aren't they both the same?

Comment: @HosseinFallah No they aren't the same ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040669/next-js-use-of-app-js-and-document-js . Try the method I sent you, use the example as documentation, I checked and it works. Good Luck and Best regards!